# How to record played audio stream by sox under windows?

Tags: windows, sox, soundcard

I want to record the "played sound" from the current soundcard using sox and stream it to another destition.

Using the microphone as a common "input device" was feasable with this code:

```
sox -t waveaudio 1 --no-show-progress --rate 16000 --channels 1 --encoding signed-integer --bits 16 --type wav -
```

But as said, I dont want to use the microphone, I want to use an output device to record a played stream.

In the tool Audacity I can do that by setting the audio host to "Windows WASAPI" and then choose the fitting loopback-device - e.g. Speakers (Realtek(R) Audio) loopback

Can you help me?

Comment: Well I guess this is not easy to achieve with sox. However, I just plugged a double male 3.5mm cable from mic to speakers and i worked :D